# Angularjs ngKeyup on select box is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, keyup

I am trying to capture "enter key" event on select box but it's not working.
Please suggest how to achieve this in angular.js.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-keyup="keyPress($event, addCDI)" tabindex="0" name="search_cdi_reason">
  <option value="item1" selected="selected">item1</option>
  <option value="item2"> item 2 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: But i need  "enter key" event not ng-chage. Please suggest if any solution for enter key press

Comment: No, Actually user will select an option then press enter which need to trigger method "addCDI"

Comment: Yes, But client want enter key press after selection to trigger method "addCDI". So I can't use ng-change because it would not be good to trigger method "addCDI" everytime on change event.

Comment: What if user changes the value using mouse ?

Comment: Hey @Shakti can you please what you want to achieve by the keypress? What functionlaity do you wish to include? Is it a string search or something for instance.?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `ng-change` instead of `ng-keyup` to trigger the change event. `ng-change` is not a directive for handling the change event (I realize that this is confusing given the name), but is actually instead notified when the model value changes (because ng-change adds a listener to the $viewChangeListeners collection).

Also note **`ng-change` function doesn't allow to pass `$event` as argument**

Try this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="addCDI()" ng-model="test" tabindex="0" name="search_cdi_reason">
    <option value="item1" selected="selected">item1</option>
    <option value="item2"> item 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative is to use ng-change which will trigger when a new option is selected.

Note that with ng-change, it is required to have ng-model as well.

Comment: But i want "enter key" event not ng-change

Comment: onchange you will get event then you can use event.keycode and enter keycode is 13.